# How to display jquery on more than 1 field?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i can not use this keypad plugin on multiple fields. The first one works perfect but the other ones do not work. what do i need to do to make it work on all?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#item_fee').keypad();            
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <tr>
      <?
        $query="SELECT * FROM item WHERE orderr_reference ='$ref' order by item_name";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        $num=mysql_numrows($result);

        $i=0;
        while ($i < $num) {

       $item_fee = mysql_result($result,$i,"item_fee");
       ?>

      <td><input name="item_fee[]" id="item_fee" type="text" value="<?=$item_fee;?>" size="6" /></td>
      </tr>
<?  $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: change id="item_fee" to class="item_fee" and update jQuery select . instead of #

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID's are unique in any one html page try this:

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.keypad input').keypad();            
});
</script>
```

Make it work for all inputs in another element with the keypad class

**HTML**

```
<body>
<table class="keypad">
```

Also make sure to update your html and remove the duplicate ID's.

Comment: Glad to help. @ingo, should've left your reply if it differed, by even a little bit.

Comment: alright. undeleted since mine differs slightly if you don't want the keypad running on all inputs within the table.

Answer (score 1):

id's are supposed to be unique for each html element in a webpage. 
so change id="item_fee" to class="item_fee"

like so `<td><input name="item_fee[]" class="item_fee" type="text" value="<?=$item_fee;?>" size="6" /></td>`

and then you cane write in jquery

```
$(function () { 
    $('.item_fee').keypad();
});
```

Comment: this is entirely viable especially if he has other type of inputs in the page, like submit buttons! :) I'd say yours is better due to this simple reason ^^

Comment: Thanks. although I'm guessing this plugin filters on type='text'. But that's just speculation and it's better to be safe than sorry :)